# Como extraer datos mas de dos datos de una columna de base de datos para llevarlas a php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

tengo la siguiente tabla

[image]

en la cual quiero extraer los datos de id_muestra que estén relacionados a id_ott, para lo cual ocupo la siguiente consulta

SELECT id_muestra FROM lacem_obras_civiles.msa_registro_muestra where id_ott=111;

Me arroja lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al extrarlos a php me devuelven solo 1

```
  if($resultadoMuestra = $mysqli_obra->query("SELECT id_muestra FROM lacem_obras_civiles.msa_registro_muestra where id_ott=$ott;")) {
 $formularioRegistroMuestra=$resultadoMuestra->fetch_array();
```

}

```
var_dump($formularioRegistroMuestra);
```

y el resultado de var_dump me muestra solo una fila

array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "368" ["id_muestra"]=> string(3) "368" }

Como hago para que muestre retorne los dos valores;

Answer (score 4):

Te muestra una sola fila porque cuando ejecutas una consulta con `query`, los datos vienen en un objeto que debe ser recorrido *fila por fila* (forma más recomendada sobre todo cuando se esperan muchos datos, para salvaguardar la memoria) o vaciados de golpe en otra parte (cuando se esperan pocas filas y se dispone de un método para ello). Sea como sea, tienes que recurrir a algún método para recuperar o mostrar los datos (los más comunes son los diferentes métodos `fetch_*` que existen).

Esos métodos `fetch_*` sirven para recorrer el conjunto de resultados *fila por fila*, devolviendo un array numérico, asociativo o ambos (según el que uses).

Cuando aplicas el método fuera de un bucle, sólo obtienes la primera fila, porque no sigues moviendo el conjunto de resultados a la siguiente fila (es lo que ocurre actualmente con tu código).

Entonces, para *vaciar*  los datos en un array por ejemplo, debes aplicar el método `fetch_*` de tu elección dentro de un bucle (el más usado es `while`), que te permitirá pasar de una fila a otra. Si haces esto, a cada paso del bucle se irá llenando el array `formularioRegistroMuestra` con cada fila del conjunto de resultados de la forma que esperas:

```
$sql="SELECT id_muestra FROM lacem_obras_civiles.msa_registro_muestra where id_ott=$ott;"
if($resultadoMuestra = $mysqli_obra->query($sql)) {

    while ($row=$resultadoMuestra->fetch_assoc()){
        /*
           *Aquí se irá llenando el array con cada fila
           *y al usar fetch_assoc cada valor quedará asociado
           *al nombre de la columna
           *Nótese que se pone [] después del nombre de tu variable
        */
        $formularioRegistroMuestra[]=$row;
    }
    print_r($formularioRegistroMuestra);
}
```

> **NÓTESE:** Que he usado `fetch_assoc` en vez de `fetch_array`, debido a que esta última te crea tanto un array numérico como asociativo por
>   cada columna. Tendrás entonces **dos veces cada valor de forma
>   innecesaria** (como de hecho muestra tu `var_dump`). Al usar `fetch_assoc` podrás acceder a cada valor usando
>   su nombre de columna, por ejemplo:
>   `$formularioRegistroMuestra["id_muestra"]`. Puedes usar también
>   `fetch_row`, y acceder usando el índice por cada columna. A mi juicio
>   `fetch_assoc` es mucho más claro.

---

> **ADVERTENCIA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD**: La consulta que estás usando es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Conviene que
>   implementes consultas preparadas para prevenir ese grave agujero de
>   seguridad en tu código.

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación de `fetch_array()` ([aca](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)) dice:

> mysqli_result::fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array — Obtiene una fila de
>   resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o ambos

O esa, que lo que esta pasando es correcto.

Cada llamada a `fetch_array()` va a retornar un registro distinto, ya que va avanzando en los mismos.

Tambien, la página de la documentación da ejemplos de como podrias leerlos todos dentro de un array:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Asi, que en tu caso, no esta trayendo uno, esta trayendo todos, pero vos solamente estas mostrando uno.