# ¿Como hacer que Select option guarde toda la cadena de caracteres y no solo la primer palabra?

Tags: php, sql, select

Uso este código

```
<select name="escuelaprocedencia" class="form-control">
    <option value="">- Selecciona -</option>
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","radx","sands");
    mysql_select_db("softn_cms",$conn);
    $consulta_mysql='select * from escuela_proce';

    $resultado_consulta_mysql=mysql_query($consulta_mysql,$conn);

    while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado_consulta_mysql)) {
        echo "<option value=".$fila['nombre_escuela']."'";
        if($fila['nombre_escuela']== $ni) {
            echo " selected='true'";
        }
        echo">".$fila['nombre_escuela']."</option>";
?>
</select>
```

Lo que hago es cargar el select option con la base de datos. Para editar el select la opcion antes elegida debe mostrarse mediante una condición, solo que al elegir nuevamente solo guarda la primer palabra y no toda la cadena.

Comment: Te falta la llave de cierre `}` del `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo seriamente que renuncies a la horrible mezcla de código PHP/HTML. Sinceramente es algo que debería estar prohibido.

Cuando necesites código HTML dentro de un bloque PHP es mejor usar una variable de concatenación para ir construyendo en ella todo el contenido. Ganarás en claridad en el código.

Es que hay que romperse bien la cabeza para analizar esto y ver dónde está el error:

```
 echo "<option value=".$fila['nombre_escuela']."'";
 if($fila['nombre_escuela']== $ni){echo " selected='true'";}
 echo">".$fila['nombre_escuela']."</option>";
```

---

Te propongo esta solución en la cual:

- Vamos a trabajar **todo el tiempo** dentro de un bloque PHP, para evitar esa horrible, confusa e inanalizable mezcla PHP/HTML
- Vamos a capturar el valor de la columna `nombre_escuela` en una variable
- Vamos a usar un ternario para agregar o no `selected` al `option` que deba llevarlo. Basta con poner `selected`, no es necesario poner `selected=true`. Cuando `selected` es omitido equivale a `false` y cuando se pone equivale a `true` ([ver W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-option-element.html#attr-option-selected) al respecto).
- Vamos a usar [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), porque es más **específico** que `fetch_array`, ya que este te trae dos resultados por cada columna, cargando mucho más la memoria ([ver nota al final de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/212260/29967)).

Este es el código, creo que se aprecia la diferencia en cuanto a claridad:

```
<?php
    $html='<select name="escuelaprocedencia" class="form-control">';
    $html.='<option value="">- Selecciona -</option>';
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","radx","sands");          
    mysql_select_db("softn_cms",$conn);
    $consulta_mysql='select * from escuela_proce';
    $resultado_consulta_mysql=mysql_query($consulta_mysql,$conn);
    while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado_consulta_mysql)){
        $nombre=$fila['nombre_escuela'];
        $value=( $nombre == $ni ) ? "value=\"$nombre\" selected" : "value=\"$nombre\"";
        $html.="<option $value>$nombre</option>";
    }
    $html.="</select>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Gracias! Resolvió mi problema, atendiendo a lo que hace como referencia de la combinación de HTML Y PHP lo tomare muy en cuenta, estoy empezando en la programación.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que tienes una comilla de cierre al final del value en esta línea, pero no tiene la comilla de apertura:

```
echo "<option value=".$fila['nombre_escuela']."'";
```

Tal vez eso es lo que hace que se guarden mal los datos, podrías corregirlo así y probar?

Agrega una comilla simple al lado del símbolo de =.